# Unidirectional association with WillCascadeOnDelete

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, cascade

I have a very simple unidirectional class mappings.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("CodeFirstDatabase")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PhoneNumber> Number { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Numbers)
            .WithOptional()
            //.Map(p => p.MapKey("ContactId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see, Contact has a list of Numbers, but Number doesn't know anything about contact (it doesn't have a property on it's parent).
What I'm trying to do here is to achieve the following:
when number is removed from contact and saved using SaveChanges, I want that number row to be removed from database, but instead, EF sets the foreign key to null and the row remains in database. Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's annoying, but EF does not offer any way to automatically delete orphans.

You have to manually delete the `PhoneNumber` instances (i.e. `context.Number.Remove(theNumber)`.

Comment: What a shame. Do you know if this is supported in EF 5? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Not that I know. If you're still in the initial stages, other ORMs do support this.