# Entity framework (6) .HasMany.WithOptional.WillCascadeOnDelete not deleting child object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I'm using entity framework with code first, and i have a simple one to many object relationship, where a *ProtoGame*-object has a List of *Country*-objects. At some point the countries will be owned by a *Game*-object instead of the *ProtoGame*.
I use fluent configuration and would like to make use of cascade-deleting, so that if the ProtoGame is deleted, the countries will also be deleted.
I use this configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProtoGame>().HasMany(u => u.Countries)
    .WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The countries are not deleted. Can anyone tell my why that is?

Comment: see this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475690/unidirectional-association-with-willcascadeondelete